# Django file upload took forever with Phusion Passenger

Tags: django, apache, file-upload, passenger

I have a Django app deployed using Passenger (I did not choose mod_wsgi because mod_passenger is already there and being used). When I uploaded an MP3 file (900 kB), Google Chrome displays upload % which reached 100% pretty fast but then it took forever for the resulting page. The database (containing the file's metadata) does not show anything uploaded.

The Django logic should be OK because everything works in the development machine (built-in Python server)

My config: Django 1.8, Apache 2.4, Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Sharing Django settings and Passenger logs will be helpful to answer.

Comment: I cannot find the passenger logs, only apache error/access logs which show nothing related.  This is not a rails app but a django app, whose root directory has not log subdirectory

Comment: I can find /tmp/passenger.1.0.1354/generation-1/buffered_uploads which is owned by www-data and has permission drwx------ The time stamp of this directory reflects the time I do the upload, but the content is always empty during the time it took for a large file upload

Comment: There is also  /tmp/passenger.1.0.1354/generation-1/logging owned by root and has permission srwxrwxrwt but the size is always zero and the timestamp stays unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passenger author here. Try setting passenger_log_level to a higher value, which may give you insights on why this is happening.

I don't know which Passenger version you are using, but in version 5, the Passenger request processing cycle looks like this:

1. Apache receives the request. Once headers are complete, it forwards the request to the Passenger server process while at the same time streaming the request body to the Passenger server process.
2. The Passenger server process buffers the entire request, including body. This buffering takes place in a temp file that is immediately unlinked.
3. Once buffering is complete, the Passenger server process forwards the request (including the body) to the Django app. Passenger then waits for the app to generate a response.
4. The Passenger server process streams the response from the Django app to Apache. No blocking buffering takes place here.
5. Apache streams the response from the Passenger server process to the client. No buffering takes place here.

With a sufficiently high log level, you can see how much time each step took so that you can pinpoint the culprit.

Note that the request processing cycle is different in earlier versions of Passenger. My advice applies only to version 5.

Comment: My passenger is: ruby-passenger:amd64/trusty 4.0.37-2  I have set  log level to 4 and I am preparing an excerpt of the error.log that I will post in the next comment.

Comment: The log excerpt is in https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-EFDVFnXfbtZXR2bnhmUG5FLWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The log file doesn't indicate anything wrong. All requests are processed almost instantly. What kind of response times are you experiencing?

Comment: And have you already tried upgrading to version 5? Version 4.0.37 is pretty old.

Comment: I can only apt-get update/upgrade packages but not install a custom package.  But I tried to upload a small text file (390 bytes) instead of the mp3 (965k) and it succeeded.  So the problem is likely to be the upload file size limit.  I have not limited Apache with things like LimitRequestBody directive, and the same Django code works for 965k mp3. So narrow down to a Passenger problem.  Is there a way to define upload file size with Passenger?

Comment: Passenger doesn't enforce an upload limit. Any limits are only enforced in the web server. Can you try upgrading to version 5 using [our APT packages](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/python/ownserver/apache/oss/trusty/install_passenger.html)?